# Error running '__rvm_make install',

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rvm

I am getting errors when I try to update ruby to 2.2.4 or 2.2.3.
I am on Osx El Capiton

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.11/x86_64/ruby-2.3.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/shishirsapkota/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.3.0 - #downloading ruby-2.3.0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.3.0 - #extracting ruby-2.3.0 to /Users/shishirsapkota/.rvm/src/ruby-2.3.0 - please wait
ruby-2.3.0 - #configuring - please wait
ruby-2.3.0 - #post-configuration - please wait
ruby-2.3.0 - #compiling - please wait
ruby-2.3.0 - #installing - please wait
Error running '__rvm_make install',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/shishirsapkota/.rvm/log/1454687438_ruby-2.3.0/install.log
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:686:in `block in <class:Installer>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:754:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from /Users/shishirsapkota/.rvm/src/ruby-2.3.0/lib/rubygems/specification.rb:821:in `block in each_spec'
    from /Users/shishirsapkota/.rvm/src/ruby-2.3.0/lib/rubygems/specification.rb:743:in `block (2 levels) in each_gemspec'
    from /Users/shishirsapkota/.rvm/src/ruby-2.3.0/lib/rubygems/specification.rb:742:in `each'
    from /Users/shishirsapkota/.rvm/src/ruby-2.3.0/lib/rubygems/specification.rb:742:in `block in each_gemspec'
    from /Users/shishirsapkota/.rvm/src/ruby-2.3.0/lib/rubygems/specification.rb:741:in `each'
    from /Users/shishirsapkota/.rvm/src/ruby-2.3.0/lib/rubygems/specification.rb:741:in `each_gemspec'
    from /Users/shishirsapkota/.rvm/src/ruby-2.3.0/lib/rubygems/specification.rb:819:in `each_spec'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:751:in `block in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:801:in `block in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:798:in `each'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:798:in `<main>'
make: *** [do-install-nodoc] Error 1
+__rvm_make:0> return 2
There has been an error while running make install. Halting the installation.
```

Then I tried **rvm get head** and **rvm install ruby-2.3.0** but I still get the same error.I am searching all day, but I couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case any one stumble in this error, I removed the .rvm folder,
then I delete ruby, and Updata_rubygems folder in directory given by "which ruby".
I reinstall rvm with stable ruby and updated ruby to 2.2.4
I worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 5):

Do you have xcode command line tool? Try installing xcode. `xcode-select --install`